# Why occur TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my code.

```
def tanh(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i]=(np.exp(2*x[i])-1)/(np.exp(2*x[i])+1)
    return x

def single_layer_perceptron(x):
    w = np.random.random(x.shape)
    result=np.dot(x, w)
    return tanh(result)

arr=np.arange(10)
print(arr)
result_list=[]
for i in range(10000):
    result_list.append(single_layer_perceptron(arr))
result_array=np.array(result_list)
print(np.mean(result_array))
print(np.std(result_array))
```

But this code returns TypeError.
What's the problem of my code?

Comment: ... so check what `result=np.dot(x, w)` is...

Comment: the indentation is incorrect, please fix.

Comment: numpy already has a tanh function

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your expected result, but since you treat `x` in `tanh` as an array, you probably want `np.multiply()` method instead of `np.dot()`

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html

```
def tanh(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i]=(np.exp(2*x[i])-1)/(np.exp(2*x[i])+1)
    return x


def single_layer_perceptron(x):
    w = np.random.random(x.shape)
    result = np.multiply(x, w)
    return tanh(result)

arr = np.arange(10)
print(arr)

result_list=[]
for i in range(10000):
    result_list.append(single_layer_perceptron(arr))

result_array=np.array(result_list)
print(np.mean(result_array))
print(np.std(result_array))
```

Result:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
0.719183400513
0.357414867082
```

Also, you can use `np.tanh(result)` instead of your function. The `result` has to be an array. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tanh.html

Answer (score 0):

You really should indicate where the error occurs.  But I can recreate it with

```
In [150]: x = np.arange(10)
In [151]: w = np.random.random(x.shape)
In [152]: w
Out[152]: 
array([ 0.15289706,  0.36766394,  0.54739275,  0.11560176,  0.33185064,
        0.27493645,  0.1237475 ,  0.908773  ,  0.50731216,  0.14327178])
In [153]: res = np.dot(x,w)
In [154]: res
Out[154]: 16.963178771225383
In [155]: len(res)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-155-8fa6b1079aa4> in <module>()
----> 1 len(res)

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

`np.dot` with 2 1d arrays returns the inner product (see its docs), an object of type `np.float64`  (a float with a numpy wrapper).  That's not an array or list, so doesn't have a `len()`, and isn't iterable.  That produces this error in your `tanh` function.